# How to allow for file download (pdf) on react front and node back website

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, pdf, web

I am making a website for a medical practice and they would like for the new patient files to be a pdf file that can be downloaded.

I have found a few answers but nothing really explains how to explicitly make a `download pdf file` button on the website with a front end framework like react. I would greatly appreciate as much detail as possible as I am still new to this.

Comment: Where is the problem? Just add the `download` attribute to an anchor (`a`). It works the same way in React

Comment: Do you already have PDF files or do you need to render PDF from HTML(or other types)?

Comment: Ofc you wont find anything on the button because the button is just a mere link to a file or api. You need to handle that endpoint on your server to send/create the pdf.

Comment: So are you saying I just include the file in my app directory and then give it an `<a>` with the src location to the folder in my directory? Explicit instructions please, very new and don't know much at all